# I got an error on 'Exception' part and i don't know why

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

When i run this code i got an error on the catch (exception e) part i don't know why and the compiler say's *"A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"*

```
        try
        {

            //Form Query which will insert Company and will output generated id 
            myCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Comp(company_name) Output Inserted.ID VALUES (@company_name)";
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_name", txtCompName);
            int companyId = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());

            //For the next scenario, in case you need to execute another command do it before committing the transaction

            myTrans.Commit();

            //Output Message in message box
            MessageBox.Show("Added", "Company Added with id" + companyId, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                myTrans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (myTrans.Connection != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An exception of type " + ex.GetType() +
                                      " was encountered while attempting to roll back the transaction.");
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("An exception of type " + e.GetType() +
                              "was encountered while inserting the data.");
            MessageBox.Show("Record was written to database.");

        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

hope for your reply! Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you search MSDN for error code (like CS0136 in your case) you'll get article explaining common cases and showing sample - [Compiler Error CS0136](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/973aa6bt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You have a variable named `e` somewhere else in the local scope and there would be no way to disambiguate between the two.

Most likely you are in an event handler with the `EventArgs` parameter named `e` and you should rename one of the `e` identifiers to something else.

The following examples demonstrate this issue:

1. A conflicting parameter name

   ```
   void MyEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e)
   //                                          ^^^
   {
       try
       {
           DoSomething();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       //              ^^^
       {
           OhNo(e);
           // Which "e" is this? Is it the Exception or the EventArgs??
       }
   }
   ```
2. A conflicting local variable

   ```
   void MyMethod()
   {
       decimal e = 2.71828;
       //     ^^^

       try
       {
           DoSomething();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       //              ^^^
       {
           OhNo(e);
           // Which "e" is this? Is it the Exception or the Decimal??
       }
   }
   ```
3. Anonymous function (lambda)

   ```
   void MyMethod()
   {
       decimal e = 2.71828;
       //     ^^^

       var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                           .Sum(e => e * e); //Which "e" to multiply?
       //                      ^^^
   }
   ```

---

Note the following does not cause the same error, because you are able to disambiguate with the `this` keyword:

```
class MyClass
{
    int e;

    void MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething(e); //Here it is the Int32 field
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OhNo(e); //Here it is the exception
            DoSomethingElse(this.e); //Here it is the Int32 field
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means earlier you have declared a variable named e, and now in the same block of code, or a block inside of it (this try/catch block) you are again declaring it. Change Exception e to `Exception except` and it might work.